# .htaccess ErrorDocument woes

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, .htaccess, errordocument

I currently have an ErrorDocument directive defined inside my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /site/error.php
```

Now if I go to a non-existent page like this on my site it works fine:

```
http://mysite.com/p
```

However if I try go to a non-existent directory, the directive doesn't work

```
http://mysite.com/random/hello
```

tries to find the document:

```
http://mysite.com/random/site/error.php
```

which of course doesn't exist.
I've searched online and all sources indicate the second example above should go to the correct file (because the leading / in the directive makes it relative to the web root), but this is apparently not the case.

I am running on Ubuntu, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess files are evaluated relative to the directory that was requested.  This is also true of directives inside `<Directory >` blocks inside your main configuration.

The simplest solution would be to move the `ErrorDocument` directive into your main Apache configuration instead of the .htaccess file.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling all modules. Try `apache2ctl configtest`. Post your apache2.conf.